# Adding tags after answer accepted?

Tags: discussion

I think it makes sense to add tags after an answer have been accepted. It would make the Q&A SEO and internal SE searchability better. If the question is a little ambivalent, but the answer clears it up with more concise definitions, does this not make sense? Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I think it completely makes sense, I do it sometimes. As you say, it's better for searches and for tag lists. And I think it's valid both for tags that were missing from the beginning and for those that make sense after the question gets answers.

[image]

**TAG ALL THE THINGS!!**

Comment: Hurray for hyperbole and a half :)

Answer (score 2):

I do it often. :) No really I do.. even if it's not 30 characters in length.